# Rotating Banner using jquery

Tags: jquery-plugins

I have been trying to animate images using jquery. I came across the following post when I was searching for examples.

http://jsfiddle.net/fwUMx/99/.

The images right now are increasing and decreasing their height in a loop. I just have a question if I can do the following using jquery?

I have 6 six ads with almost same size. All ads to randomly rotate within those 6 spots so one ad is not always at top or on the bottom.
When the ads rotate, they can either flash in or quickly fade in for 5 seconds.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the always-excellent [jQuery Cycle plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).